# Extract specific information from pandas data frame

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, pandas-groupby

My data frame looks like -

```
id                                           text
1               ><body lang="EN-IN" link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72"><div class="WordSection1"><p 
                class="MsoNormal">I am interested.</p><p class="MsoNormal">I need :</p><p 
                class="MsoNormal">330 wp</p><p class="MsoNormal">50 modules</p><p 
                class="MsoNormal">&nbsp;</p><table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" 
                cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="0" style="width:282.0pt; border- 
                collapse:collapse">

2               ><body lang="EN-IN" link="#0563C1" vlink="#954F72"><div class="WordSection1"><p 
               class="MsoNormal">I am not interested.</p><p 
               class="MsoNormal">&nbsp;</p><table class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" 
               cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="0" style="width:282.0pt; border- 
               collapse:collapse">
```

My final data frame looks like -

```
id                                           text                         final_text                                              
1               ><body lang="EN-IN" link="#0563C1"                     I am interested. I need
                 vlink="#954F72"><div class="WordSection1"><p          330 wp  50 modules    
                class="MsoNormal">I am interested.</p>
                <p class="MsoNormal">I need :</p><p 
                class="MsoNormal">330 wp</p><p 
                class="MsoNormal">50 modules</p><p 
                class="MsoNormal">&nbsp;</p><table 
                 class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" 
                cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" 
                width="0" style="width:282.0pt; border- 
                collapse:collapse">

2               ><body lang="EN-IN" link="#0563C1"                      I am not interested.
                vlink="#954F72"><div class="WordSection1"><p 
               class="MsoNormal">I am not interested.</p><p 
               class="MsoNormal">&nbsp;</p><table 
               class="MsoNormalTable" border="0" 
               cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" 
               width="0" style="width:282.0pt; border- 
               collapse:collapse">
```

logic should be capture all the information which exist in between `<p class="MsoNormal"> and </p>.` But not include this string `"&nbsp"`. I want to do it in pythons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

usually people don't post such questions as "give me the code for this". You can try to post the same question as "how to remove tags from sentences that look like this" or something.

In any case, here is your solution.

```
def get_sent(s):
    sent = ' '.join([i[1:] for i in s[1:].replace('>','|~').replace('<','|').split('|') if i[:1]=='~' and len(i)>1 and i[:2]!='~&'])
    return sent

df['final_text'] = df['text'].apply(get_sent)
```

Hope this helps.